# video-js will not work in IE11

Tags: javascript, html

as the title says I can't get video-js to work in internet explorer 11. I don't know if my html code is wrong. I can get it to work in ms edge, google chrome and firefox but ie11 will not play video. The video source is a live .m3u8 stream coming from an nginx server. In the headers of the html code I use this:

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/videojs-contrib-hls/dist/videojs-contrib-hls.js"></script>
```

and in the body I use this:

```
<video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="365"
  data-setup='{}'>
    <src="http://<my-nginx-server>/mobile/index.m3u8" source type="application/x-mpegurl">
  </video>
```

I haven't been able to find a simple demo page that incorporates video-js working in IE11. I've been on this for days so hanks for any help.

Comment: `<src="http://<my-nginx-server>/mobile/index.m3u8" source type="application/x-mpegurl">` this is? (not a valid element)

Comment: Seems you've put the `src` attribute before the actual `source` element name - perhaps IE11 isn't parsing it, while other browsers may be more forgiving.

Comment: https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/4604 seems like a known issue

Comment: thankyou for the responses here. @Jaromanda if the src line is not a valid element, can you tell what is? And I don't understand about the src attribute before the source element name. I'd be grateful if you could clarify what you mean with an example. Thanks.